# React Native Swipeable (Swipe to delete) not closing

Tags: ios, react-native, swipe, react-native-gesture-handler

I'm using Swipeable from React-Native-Gesture-Handler to incorporate swipe to delete on my page.
When I press delete, the contact gets deleted however the swipeable remains open.

I want it to close after it gets pressed but I can't seem to figure out how to do it.

This is my code:

```
const RightActions = (progress, dragX) => { 
return (
<TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{DeleteContact(i)}}>
  <View style={[ContactsStyles.rightAction]}>
    <Text style={ContactsStyles.actionText}>Delete</Text>
  </View>
</TouchableOpacity>
) 
}
```

Here is where I have Swipeable:

```
<Swipeable renderRightActions={RightActions} >

     <View style={ContactsStyles.UserContainer}>

         <Text numberOfLines={1} style={[Fonts.Name]}> {obj.firstname} {obj.lastname} </Text>


         {/* Message/Call Container */}
          <View style={ContactsStyles.ImageCont}>
                    {/* Message */}
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={()  => Communications.text(obj.phone, 'Hey ' + obj.firstname + ', im in need of a Ryde. Are you able to pick me up? This is my current location: ' + location)} >
                      <View style={ContactsStyles.ImageBox}>
                        <Image style={ContactsStyles.Image} source={require('../../assets/icons/message.png')} />
                      </View>
                    </TouchableOpacity>

                    {/* Call */}
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress = {() => Communications.phonecall( obj.phone , true)}>
                      <View style={ContactsStyles.ImageBox}>
                        <Image style={ContactsStyles.Image} source={require('../../assets/icons/phone.png')} />
                      </View>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                  </View>
                  {/* End of Message/Call Container */}
      </View>
</Swipeable>
```

[image: Swipeable button doesnt disappear after on press]

Answer (score 20):

You need to use a reference which has a close method on it.

First define a ref

```
const swipeableRef = useRef(null);
```

then assign it to Swipeable

```
<Swipeable
  ref={swipeableRef}
  renderLeftActions={renderLeftActions}
  onSwipeableLeftOpen={() => handleComplete(item)}
>
    ...
</Swipeable>
```

and then just call the close method

```
const closeSwipeable = () => {
  swipeableRef.current.close();
}
```

Note, for multiple Swipeables you should have [multiple refs](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-gesture-handler/issues/764#issuecomment-570411610).

```
let row: Array<any> = [];
let prevOpenedRow;

renderItem ({ item, index }) {
  return (
    <Swipeable
      ref={ref => row[index] = ref}
      friction={2}
      leftThreshold={80}
      rightThreshold={40}
      renderRightActions={renderRightActions}
      containerStyle={style.swipeRowStyle}
      onSwipeableOpen={closeRow(index)}
      ...
    >
    ...
    </Swipeable>);
}

closeRow(index) {
  if (prevOpenedRow && prevOpenedRow !== row[index]) {
    prevOpenedRow.close();
  }
  prevOpenedRow = row[index];
}
```

Comment: This works but it shows the `close` animation on the next-listed element (which has now moved up into the deleted item's position)

Answer (score 8):

It's an [index issue](https://github.com/jemise111/react-native-swipe-list-view/issues/455#issuecomment-618104389) . When we have our list keyed on `index`, and we remove one item (eg index=3), the next item (previously index=4) now adopts the earlier index. Swipeable gets confused by this.

The answer is to key the list on something other than index (eg a unique `id`).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. What I did to solve that was to set the state array (which is shown in a list) to [] first before deleting that particular item. It cleared-up the screen (including the action panel) and rendered new items.

A part of my code:

```
const [notes, setNotes] = useState([]);

<FlatList
        data={notes}
......
```

when a note was deleted, I did: setNotes([]) and then setNotes(newNotes)

Answer (score 0):

The solution to problem is **to create a reference** so that the swipeable may return to its initial position.

For this, import useRef from React and initialze it to null:

```
const swipeableRef = useRef(null);
```

Now you have the initial reference and use this reference to close the swipeable when you do function execution.
Pass this to

```
<Swipeable ref = {swipeableRef}>
```

Do the following:

```
function yourFunction() {
   swipeableRef.current.close();

// enter code here

}
```

This way the swipeable will close first and then the function execution will work.

Happy Coding!